# .exeファイルの文字化けに関して

Tags: windows, vscode, 文字化け, 文字コード, mingw

Windows10でVS codeとMinGWを利用しています。MinGWは「mingw32-base」と「mingw32-gcc-g++」をインストールして、バージョンは6.3.0です。

hello　worldと表示するだけの簡単なプログラムを書き、「gcc ファイル名.c」として.exeファイルができたのですが、コードで「printf("円\n")」と書きgccでコンパイルした後、VS codeのターミナルにて「.\a.exe」でファイルを実行するとコードで「円」の部分が「蜀・」として返ってきます。特に設定を変更した覚えはないです。
files.encodingは既定値のUTF8です。文字コードが原因でしょうか？ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: @Koko さん、`.\a.exe` は人間が読むためのテキストファイルではなく、主に機械語が並んだバイナリファイルです。VSCode はテキストエディタですので、例外はありますが基本的にはテキストファイルを読むために使います。`.\a.exe` はバイナリファイルであり、文字化け以前にそもそも何か意味のある文字列になっていません。こういった事情の元、ご質問の中で「`.\a.exe` をターミナルで実行すると文字化けする」と「`.\a.exe` をエディタで開くと文字化けする」が混在しており、Koko さんがどのような問題意識をお持ちなのか私からはよく分からなくなってしまっています。Koko さんが行いたいのはどういったことなのでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、丁寧な説明ありがとうございます。a.exeもなにか意味のあるテキストファイルであると勘違いをしておりました。解決したいのは「.\a.exe」をターミナルで実行すると、コードでは「円」だった部分が「蜀・」と異なった文字列で返ってくる部分です。

Comment: MinGWにもバリエーションやバージョンが色々あり、対策も違う場合があるため、具体的に記述してください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**文字化けの原因：**
ソースコード`printf("円\n")`が`UTF-8`ですが、Windows(VSCode)ターミナルのデフォルトエンコードは`ShiftJIS`です。

**対策：**
VSCodeでファイルのエンコードを`ShiftJIS`に変更します。

1. `UTF-8`をクリック
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
2. `Save with Encoding`を選択
3. `Shift JIS`を選択
4. 再コンパイル

Answer (score 3):

WindowsにはWide（常にUTF-16）とANSI（設定により変更可能、日本語ではShift-JISのみ）の２種類の世界が存在します。それぞれについて説明します。他の方の回答はいずれも不完全なので補足します。また実行手段として質問のVSCode上のTerminalの他にコマンドプロンプトについても説明します。

---

### WideでUTF-16を扱う方法

ソースコードはUTF-8を使用します。`printf`でなく[`wprintf`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf)を使用します。更に文字列はWide文字列を使用する必要があります。これによりコンパイル時にUTF-8からWide文字に変換されます。またWindows版`wprintf`の仕様として[`setlocale`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) or `_wsetlocale`によるロケール設定の必要があります。これにより実行時にWide文字が指定のロケールで解釈されます。

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"");
    wprintf(L"円\n");
}
```

実行方法については特別な操作は必要ありません。

---

### ANSIでUTF-8を扱う方法

nekketsuuuさんの回答です。ソースコードはUTF-8を使用します。`printf`がUTF-8を出力していることを出力先に伝える必要があります。その方法は事前に`chcp 65001`コマンドを実行するか、プログラム内で[`SetConsoleOutputCP`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp)を実行するか、どちらでも実現できます。なお、[Windows版`setlocale` or `_wsetlocale`はUTF-8に対応していない](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=vs-2017)ため使用できません。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);  // CP_UTF8 = 65001
    printf("円\n");
}
```

実行方法としては先に説明した通り、プログラム内で`SetConsoleOutputCP`を実行しない場合は事前に`chcp 65001`コマンドを実行します。
VSCode上のTerminalではそのまま実行できますが、コマンドプロンプトは正しくフォントを設定しないとフォント化けします。具体的には`cmd.exe`を実行するショートカットを作成し、そのショートカットのプロパティ内でフォントとして`ＭＳ ゴシック`を選択する必要があります（コマンドプロンプト左上のコントロールメニュー内の`既定値`や`プロパティ`からでは正しく設定できない）。

---

### ANSIでShift-JISを扱う方法

Jiuさんの回答です。ソースコードはShift-JISを使用します。なお、[Shift-JISは`表`など２バイト名が`\`と同じコードとなる文字が存在](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS#2%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%8C5C%E7%AD%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%86%E3%82%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C)します。そのままではC++言語上で`\`と解釈され構文エラーや文字化け等を引き起こします。g++に対してコンパイルオプション`-finput-charset=CP932 -fexec-charset=CP932`でShift-JISソースコードを扱っていることを伝える必要があります。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("円\n");
}
```

実行方法については特別な操作は必要ありません。が、前述のパターンでコードページを`65001`に変更している場合は、`chcp 932`で日本語に戻しておく必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

VSCode のターミナルで実行されているコマンドプロンプト (cmd.exe) は、設定によってデフォルトの文字コードが Shift_JIS (正確には [CP932](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8932)) になっています。ソースコードの文字コードが UTF-8 だと、この違いが原因で文字化けすることがあります。

たとえば適当なアップデートを適用した Windows 10 の場合、cmd.exe の文字コードを UTF-8 に変更するコマンド

```
chcp 65001
```

を実行したあと `a.exe` を実行して文字化けが直るのであれば、文字コードの差が原因です。なお、Shift_JIS には

```
chcp 932
```

で戻すことができます。

現代的には Unicode に揃えるのが良いでしょうから、cmd.exe のデフォルト文字コードを UTF-8 にしてしまいましょう。上記の `chcp 65001` は cmd.exe を起動するたびに打ち直さないといけないので、`cmd.exe` を起動した際に自動的に `chcp 65001` するようなオプション付きで起動させるようにしてみます。これは cmd.exe の `/K` オプションでできるのですが、VSCode の場合デフォルト・シェルの設定をすることでオプションを追加することができます。

ファイル→基本設定→設定

```json
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "/K",
        "chcp",
        "65001"
    ]
```

参考: [VSCodeのcmdをUTF-8で使う](https://qiita.com/te2ji/items/873e1bb42ef9b3a52c1d) -- Qiita